# dotnet Maui custom control specific sizing (square)

Tags: .net, controls, maui

I have been searching around but I was unable to find to do what I want to do.. Maybe I am simply overcomplicating things.

I have an app that should show a custom control somewhere (skiasharp canvas). However, it should be perfectly square.

In the custom control there is a function: public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect) where dirtyRect gives me the actual size of the control which i can use to draw. But I can not change the size here.

For now, I seem to be able to 'get close' by using a grid and some other controls with "HeightRequest", but that is not how I want to get it done.

Ideally, the control would be the full width (minus margins whatever) of the mobile device, and the height would match that. If the height would not be possible due to sizing of the mobile device, then the width should become less in such a way that the canvas stays square, but gets more horizontal margin.

How would I be able to do this, where to start?

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could experiment with is inheriting `Grid` to make a custom control that maintains an *internal* `IDrawable` since there's little use in having the user of the control be required to pass a canvas into the `CustomControl` in order to draw it.  This paradigm loosely emulates what a Winforms control would do. You call `Refresh()` and the custom control responds with a Draw event that provides a canvas on which the user is free to draw.

As far as squaring it up, I went about this by subscribing to `ContentPage.SizeChanged` events by traversing up the visual tree to the root view. Screenshots from Windows and Android physical devices are shown.

[image: Win UI build]

---

Here's  a proto I tested across platforms:

```cs
public partial class CustomControl : Grid
{
    private readonly GraphicsView _graphics;
    private bool _isLoaded = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Actions that are 'always' drawn on invalidate that define the look of the control.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Action<ICanvas, RectF>> InternalDrawDocument { get; } = new List<Action<ICanvas, RectF>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Actions that can be injected by the user.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Action<ICanvas, RectF>> UserDrawDocument { get; } = new List<Action<ICanvas, RectF>>();

    public CustomControl()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsView
        {
            Drawable = new InnerDrawable(this),
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        };
        Children.Add(_graphics); // Add the GraphicsView to the control's visual tree

        PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Window) && !_isLoaded)
            {
                _isLoaded = true;
                // Subscribe to page size changes
                if (this.FindAncestorOfType<ContentPage>() is ContentPage page)
                {
                    page.SizeChanged += OnPageSizeChanged;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

###### InternalDrawDocument

This is a list of `Action<ICanvas, RectF>` that constitute a 'Document' that will be drawn upon refresh.
Here's where this particular control draws the standard 'concentric circles" that define its native appearance.

```
   protected virtual void OnPageSizeChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (sender is ContentPage page)
       {
           double scaling = 1.0;
           int squareDimension = (int)(scaling * Math.Max(100, Math.Min(page.Height, page.Width)));
           HeightRequest = squareDimension;
           WidthRequest = squareDimension;

           Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
           {
               InternalDrawDocument.Clear();
               UserDrawDocument.Clear();      // Maybe you 
               _graphics.Invalidate();
           });
           Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
           {
               var decr = (int)(WidthRequest / 40f);
               for (int radius = (int)WidthRequest / 2; radius > 0; radius -= decr)
               {
                   // This will 'not' work unless you capture
                   // the radius in a variable that exists just for this loop.
                   var loopScopeRadius = radius;
                   var drawAction = ((ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect) =>
                   {
                       canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Blue;
                       canvas.DrawCircle((float)(HeightRequest / 2), (float)(HeightRequest / 2), loopScopeRadius);
                   });
                   InternalDrawDocument.Add(drawAction);
               }
               _graphics.Invalidate();
           });
       }
   }

   public void Refresh() =>_graphics.Invalidate();
```

##### Inner IDrawable

Responds to IDrawable.Draw to paint the control, but also invokes the custom control's Draw event so that the user can make use of the canvas.

```
    private class InnerDrawable : IDrawable
    {
        private readonly CustomControl _parent;

        public InnerDrawable(CustomControl parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
        }

        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
        {
            foreach (var action in _parent.InternalDrawDocument)
            {
                action.Invoke(canvas, dirtyRect);
            }
            foreach (var action in _parent.UserDrawDocument)
            {
                action.Invoke(canvas, dirtyRect);
            }
            _parent.Draw?.Invoke(this, new DrawEventArgs(canvas,  dirtyRect));
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler<DrawEventArgs>? Draw;
    protected virtual void OnDraw(DrawEventArgs e)
    {
        Draw?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
public class DrawEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DrawEventArgs(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        Canvas = canvas;
        DirtyRect = dirtyRect;
    }

    public ICanvas Canvas { get; }
    public RectF DirtyRect { get; }
}

public static partial class Extensions
{
    public static T? FindAncestorOfType<T>(this Element element) where T : Element
    {
        while (element != null)
        {
            if (element is T correctType)
            {
                return correctType;
            }
            element = element.Parent;
        }

        return default;
    }
}
```

---

##### User Draw

Here is an example of the user injecting actions into the `UserDrawDocument` to be
included during refreshes. In this case it will animate a horizontal centered red line.

[image: andoid screenshots]

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void OnDrawClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
        {
            drawableControl.UserDrawDocument.Clear();
            drawableControl.Refresh();
        });
        Dispatcher.Dispatch(async() =>
        {
            for(float f1 = 100f, f2 = 105f; f2 < drawableControl.Width - 100f; f1 += 5f, f2 += 5f)
            {
                float loopScopeF1 = f1;
                float loopScopeF2 = f2;
                drawableControl.UserDrawDocument.Add((canvas, r) =>
                {
                    canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
                    canvas.DrawLine(loopScopeF1, (float)(drawableControl.Height / 2), loopScopeF2, (float)(drawableControl.Height / 2));
                });
                drawableControl.Refresh();
                await Task.Delay(1);
            }
        });
    }

    private void OnDrawClear(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drawableControl.UserDrawDocument.Clear();
        drawableControl.Refresh();
    }
}
```

**MainPage xaml**

This shows the placement of the custom control on the main page.

```xml
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SquareCustomControl"
    x:Class="SquareCustomControl.MainPage"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            <local:CustomControl
                x:Name="drawableControl"
                BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
                <HorizontalStackLayout
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="End">
                    <Button 
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        WidthRequest="150"
                        BackgroundColor="RoyalBlue" 
                        Text="Draw"
                        Clicked="OnDrawClicked"/>    
                    <Button 
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        WidthRequest="150"
                        BackgroundColor="LightSalmon" 
                        Text="Clear"
                        Clicked="OnDrawClear"/>                    
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </local:CustomControl>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

This is definitely a first pass, but I found your question interesting enough that I wanted to give it some thought and I hope it's useful in this rough form.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/SquareCustomControl.git)